# how to make keyboard enter and exit screen smoothly

Tags: android, keyboard

when I click the edit text in my app, the keyboard sort of jumps in, instead of sliding in smoothly, as well as when i press the back button, it disappears by jumping

note there is a view at the bottom that it pushes up

how can i make the keyboard appear and disappear smoothly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the android:windowSoftInputMode attribute to the activity in which you are working in the AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<activity android:name="youractivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

adjustPan causes the keyboard to move in smoothly and push up your views, other modes can be found at 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode